# In C++, how to assign a hex value to a letter/string gotten from user input?

Tags: c++, string, hex

I need some help. Currently I'm writing a program where the user inputs a sentence, the sentence is put into a string, then the string is broken up and each character is displayed on a 7-segment display for 2 seconds each. The problem I'm having is how to assign a hex value to each character; when each character is parsed from the string, naturally it's using its ASCII decimal value. However, the ASCII decimal value will not display the appropriate character on the 7-segment display, which is why I need to change the value so if a user inputs an "h" it'll actually look like an "h" on the display. Could someone please help? I've tried a few things, like '(letter)' == (0x__), but it still displays using the ASCII decimal value.

```
std::string input = "";

cout << "Please enter a valid sentence (with spaces):\n>";
getline(cin, input);
transform(input.begin(), input.end(), input.begin(), toupper);
cout << "You entered: " << input << endl << endl;


for (char& c : input) {
    OutputData(c);
    Sleep(2000);
    cout << c << endl;
}
```

Comment: Start by *defining* a mapping of every English letter to a hex digit. Express that mapping in C++, e.g. as a `std::map<char, char>`. Then use that C++ mapping to, well, map letters to hex digits.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want a large switch case statement:

```
switch (c) {
    case '0':
        // write 0 on the seven segment display
        break;

    case '1':
        // write 1 on the seven segment display
        break;

    ...

    case 'Z':
        // write Z on the seven segment display
        break;

    default:
        // A character that is not handled by a case.
        // Do something useful.
        break;
}
```

Alternatively, build a lookup table and use that.

Comment: I see. For example, under `case Z:` and before the break, I would write `c=(hex value I want)`, so when the user inputs a "Z" it retrieves the value for c that will make it look like a "Z" on the 7-segment display, correct?